# Swift iOS -How to hide tabBar in specific tab but not other tabs when device rotates

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, device-orientation

My app is tab based and portrait only. Inside a specific view controller I have a 16x9 view pinned to the top of the scene that shows video like YouTube does when in `.portrait` orientation. Also like YoutTube I allow that specific vc to rotate to `.landscapeRight` or `.landscapeLeft` to show that video in full screen mode. I call `func canRotate()` to make that happen and I have the functionally for that implemented inside AppDelegate. None of the other tabs or vcs can rotate.

Inside the vc with the video when the device rotates I use a Notification to determine the orientation and since the video is showing full screen in either `.landscapeRight` or `.landscapeLeft`I hide the tab bar.

The problem I'm having is that when I'm on a different tab such as tab2 or tab3, when I rotate the device, the tabBar gets hidden because of what's happening inside the VideoVC. The other tabs/vcs don't rotate but the tabBar disappears when in `.landscapeRight` or `.landscapeLeft` orientation

**How can I keep the tabBar hidden inside the VideoVC when the device is rotated but not hidden inside the other tabs?**

Inside tab0 this is the VideoVC:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange(){

        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {

        case .landscapeRight:

            view.transform = transform.rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        case .landscapeLeft:

            view.transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        case .portrait:

            view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

        default: break
        }
}

@objc func canRotate(){} // allows this vc to rotate
```

AppDelegate:

```
...if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {
          // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
          return .allButUpsideDown;
   }
```

I tried using a Notification to disable hiding the tabBar in other tabs that have vcs that can't rotate but it was screwy. It prevented the tabBar from being hidden in the VideoVC on rotation or if I rotated the video inside the VideoVC before pressing the Notifications tab then it would still hide the tabBar there.

NotificationVC:

```
@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange(){

        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {

        case .landscapeRight, .landscapeLeft, .portrait:
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false    

        defaults: break
        }
}
```

tab0 with VideoVC .portrait (can rotate):

[image: tab0 with VideoVC .portrait]

tab0 with VideoVC .landscapeLeft (can rotate):

[image: tab0 with VideoVC .landscapeLeft]

tab3 with NotificationsVC .portrait (can't rotate):

[image: tab3 with NotificationsVC .portrait]

tab3 with NotificationsVC .landscapeLeft (can't rotate but tabBar is hidden and shouldn't be -this is the problem):

[image: tab3 with NotificationsVC .landscapeLeft]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is simple (although it took hours to figure out). All I had to do was check to see if the view.window != nil and wrap what was in the notification's selector inside of it.

```
if (self.view.window != nil) {
   // put the what's inside the notification's selector in here
}
```

The problem was since the VideoVC and the NotificationsVC were both instantiated, the Notification I used to detect the orientation change was checking on the UIDevice itself wether the VideoVC’s view was visible or not. No matter what vc I was in it would still respond to whatever the device was told to do with the tabbar on an orientation change.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange(){

        // no matter what vc I was in this was still running
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {

        case .landscapeRight:

            view.transform = transform.rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        case .landscapeLeft:

            view.transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        case .portrait:

            view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

        default: break
        }
}
```

The fix was to wrap the UIDevice.current.orientation switch statement inside `if (self.view.window != nil) {}` and the NotifcationsVC no longer responded to the device orientation because the VideoVC window was no longer visible.

**Code:**

```
@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange(){

    // use this to check if this view's window isn't nil
    if (self.view.window != nil) {

        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {

           case .landscapeRight:

            view.transform = transform.rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        case .landscapeLeft:

            view.transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

        case .portrait:

            view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

        default: break
        }
    }
}
```